# Scala Map foreach

Tags: scala, scala-collections

given:

```
val m = Map[String, Int]("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3)
m.foreach((key: String, value: Int) => println(">>> key=" + key + ", value=" + value))
```

why does the compiler complain

```
error: type mismatch
found   : (String, Int) => Unit
required: (String, Int) => ?
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

oops, read the doco wrong, map.foreach expects a function literal with a tuple argument!

so

```
m.foreach((e: (String, Int)) => println(e._1 + "=" + e._2))
```

works

Comment: Given that types involved are inferred, you could simply do: m.foreach(e => println(e._1 + "=" + e._2)

Comment: Is is possible to show the full type? There are a lot of Maps, I'm concerned about which one is it.

Answer (score 82):

I'm not sure about the error, but you can achieve what you want as follows:

```
m.foreach(p => println(">>> key=" + p._1 + ", value=" + p._2))
```

That is, `foreach` takes a function that takes a pair and returns `Unit`, not a function that takes two arguments: here, `p` has type `(String, Int)`.

Another way to write it is:

```
m.foreach { case (key, value) => println(">>> key=" + key + ", value=" + value) }
```

In this case, the `{ case ... }` block is a partial function.

Comment: that's nice, more in line with dynamic language obj.each {k,v => ...} approach and more readable than tuple ._1, ._2 syntax

Comment: Juts curious, is there any performance consideration for second usage(case)? For each element try to 'case' them assign to variable etc. I want my code readable but also to fast as possible as.

Answer (score 19):

You need to patter-match on the `Tuple2` argument to assign variables to its subparts `key`, `value`. You can do with very few changes:

```
m.foreach{ case (key: String, value: Int) => println(">>> key=" + key + ", value=" + value)}
```

Comment: And you can remove type annotations from key and value, by the way.

Answer (score 14):

The confusing error message is a compiler bug, which should be [fixed in 2.9.2](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5067):

Comment: I've just checked (by compiling https://github.com/paulbutcher/baderrormessage against both 2.9.1 and 2.9.2). I can see the problem in 2.9.1 and not in 2.9.2. If you have an example of the problem still occurring, perhaps you should reopen the bug?

Comment: I have just tried the code posted in the answer by @(Eishay Smith) below (I believe is the exact same problem as shown in the question) with Scala 2.9.2 (Java HotSpot 1.7.0 VM for Windows 64-bit ) and can see the same absurd message shown in his post.

Comment: Here is what happens when I compile your code from Git:   Welcome to Scala version 2.9.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> class Foo extends Function2[Int, Int, Int] {
     |   def apply(x: Int, y: Int) = x + y
     |   override def tupled: (Int, Int) => Int = super.tupled
     | }
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : ((Int, Int)) => Int
 required: (Int, Int) => Int
         override def tupled: (Int, Int) => Int = super.tupled
                                                        ^

Comment: That error message is correct. Note that there are two sets of parentheses in the "found" line. The bug was that it used to print only a single set of parentheses. If you try it in 2.9.1 and diff the output, you will see that they are different.

Answer (score 5):

Excellent question!
Even when explicitly typing the foreach method, it still gives that very unclear compile error. There are ways around it, but I can't understand why this example does not work.

```
scala> m.foreach[Unit] {(key: String, value: Int) => println(">>> key=" + key + ", value=" + value)}
<console>:16: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (String, Int) => Unit
 required: (String, Int) => Unit
              m.foreach[Unit] {(key: String, value: Int) => println(">>> key=" + key + ", value=" + value)}
                                                         ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Docs says argument is tuple -> unit, so We can easily do this

```
Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2).foreach(tuple => println(tuple._1 +" " + tuple._2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way:

```
Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2).foreach(((x: Int, y: Int) => ???).tupled)
```

However it requires explicit type annotations, so I prefer partial functions.