# How can I write my immutable Map foreach in scala?

Tags: scala, dictionary, foreach

I am trying to use the `foreach` method on `scala.collection.immutable.Map`.  But no matter how I change my format, I receive a compilation error.  I have referenced the question: [Scala Map foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610776/scala-map-foreach), but it still doesn't work:

```
val m = Map[String, Int]("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3)
m.foreach(p => println(">>> key=" + p._1 + ", value=" + p._2))
```

or:

```
val m = Map[String, Int]("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3)
m.foreach((e: (String, Int)) => println(e._1 + "=" + e._2))
```

both report:

```
type mismatch; found : Unit required: String
```

My Scala library version is 2.10.4 and my eclipse version is Release 4.3.2.

Comment: it appears that it believes that the result of this entire computation should be String based on some surrounding context that you haven't shown us, however the type of foreach (and thus your entire expression) is Unit

Comment: Yah, we need more. The lines provided work

Comment: You might have intented to use `map` followed by `mkString` to convert your `Map` into `String`. In that case remove `println`.